# Same id for 2 dropdown unable to perform actions om 2 one

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automation

In my code there are 2 dropdowns on 2 different pages and they both have same id "birth-nation". I am able to perform the actions by using this id but when it goes to second it gives me an error that element is not visible.

Here is my code:

```
Select dropdown1111111 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("birth-nation")));
dropdown1111111.selectByVisibleText("UNITED STATES");


Select dropdown1111111 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("birth-nation")));
dropdown1111111.selectByVisibleText("UNITED STATES");
```

The id for both are same and I am not able to perform actions on 2 dropdown.

HTML File below.
for 1 element:

```
 <select required="" name="birthNation" id="birth-nation" class="formcontrol input-sm sync valid" data-sync-to-element="#personal-info-view-birth_nation-243202808" aria-invalid="false">
```

for 2 element:

```
 <select required="" name="birthNation" id="birth-nation" class="form-control input-sm sync" data-sync-to-element="#personal-info-view-birth_nation-243202809">
```

Comment: Update the question with the relevant html

Comment: if you go look into your developer tools of your browser (f12 in chrome) do you see the element twice in the elements tab? 
You can try selecting it with the corresponding xPath

Comment: @SE God I think he mean that the same drop-down is present on two different pages.

Comment: Yes both of them are present on 2 different pages

Comment: for 1 element: <select required="" name="birthNation" id="birth-nation" class="form-control input-sm sync valid" data-sync-to-element="#personal-info-view-birth_nation-243202808" aria-invalid="false"> for 2 element: <select required="" name="birthNation" id="birth-nation" class="form-control input-sm sync" data-sync-to-element="#personal-info-view-birth_nation-243202809">

Comment: The id is same for both and class as well the only difference is the numerical value, I do not know how I can use this difference to select my 2 dropdown. help

Comment: Posting a link to the page would be the fastest way to get an answer. For the second page, is there something you have to do to get the dropdown to be visible? Have you tried a wait? How do you know you are finding the right element?

Comment: @JeffC I have inspected the element and also tried is displayed so I am sure that I am finding the right element

Comment: possible duplicate issue with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50618697/same-element-id-on-2-different-pages-unable-to-sendkeys-to-2-one?noredirect=1#comment88248065_50618697

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below CSS Selector as only difference in your attribute is on **#personal-info-view-birth_nation**

```
select[id = "birth-nation"][data-sync-to-element = "#personal-info-view-birth_nation-243202808"]

select[id = "birth-nation"][data-sync-to-element = "#personal-info-view-birth_nation-243202809"]
```

Comment: you mean to use it like Select dropdown1111111 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#personal-info-view-birth_nation-243202808"))); right?

Comment: I had given the CSS selector in my answer, you have to use that.

Comment: It is working good now thanks buddy but there is block where of email where  i have to input a email address and it is failing there here is the code for that driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select[id = \"email-address\"][data-sync-to-element = \"#personal-info-view-email_address-243202809\"]")).sendKeys("ncl.reservation12345@gmail.com");

Comment: @SarveshSingh - Please mark this as an answer and ask a new question.and add the link here