# Same element id on 2 different pages unable to sendKeys to 2 one

Tags: java, selenium

In my project there are 2 elements in 2 different pages in  which I want to sendKeys and they both have same element id

they have a quite difference in between them

```
<input type="text" required="" name="emergencyContactName" id="emergency-contact" 
       class="form-control input-sm sync valid" value="Sarvesh Singh" 
       data-sync-to-element="#contact-info-view-emergency_contact_name-243202808" 
       aria-invalid="false">
```

```
<input type="text" required="" name="emergencyContactName" id="emergency-contact" 
       class="form-control input-sm sync" value="" 
       data-sync-to-element="#contact-info-view-emergency_contact_name-243202809">
```

I am able to sendKeys for the 1 element by using the below code:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("emergency-contact")).sendKeys("Sarvesh Singh");
```

But When I try to use the same code for 2 element by the below code:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("emergency-contact")).sendKeys("Sarvesh Singh");
```

It is giving me and error:

> “element is not visible “

Please help

Same thing happenns for element Email address and phone number as well, so I am stuck in it.

Comment: Please add source code sample and more of your own code including the exception.

Comment: "element is not visible" is quite explicit, did you check if you can send keys manually on the page?

Comment: @pburgr please see the html code of both elements

Comment: @MincongHuang yes I am able to enter the value manually on the page

Comment: If the elements are in different pages, how do go or switch to the second page? If you don't, that's why the second element is not visible.

Comment: It does not go and load a new page "when I click on submit and move to next step" it just changes the column and then go to the new column and then it is not taking the element  @pburgr

Comment: Now I get it. Do you wait for visibility of the second element?

Comment: @pburgr yes I put a thread sleep for 15 seconds as well.

Comment: try to find the second element with this xpath: "//input[contains(@value,'')]"     note: there are two simple quotation marks after value,

Comment: btw better to avoid thread.sleep with:   WebDriverWait wait15s = new WebDriverWait(driver,15);
WebElement myElement = wait15s.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By. ...); if the element is clickable in 3 seconds, you spare 12 seconds. Lots of sleeps increases test duration.

Comment: @pburgr I have tried this now but it is not working : driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@value,'contact-info-view-emergency_contact_name-243202809')]")).sendKeys("Sarvesh Singh");

Comment: error: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[contains(@value,'contact-info-view-emergency_contact_name-243202809')]"}

Comment: keep the value in xpath empty. Since the first element already has a value and the second has not, xpath with empty value should find the second element. driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@value,'')]")).sendKeys("Sarvesh Singh");

Comment: @pburgr I used your code and its still giving the same error: Element not visible   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@value,'')]")).sendKeys("Sarvesh Singh");

Comment: try with click before sendkeys: WebElement e2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@value,'')]"));
e2.click();
e2.sendKeys("Sarvesh Singh"); split the code to more lines to see, where comes the exception.

Comment: @pburgr it still shows the same error on the line e2.click();

Comment: can you provide url so I can test it by myself?

Comment: @pburgr  I can not do that because of client confidentiality

Comment: try to fill up the filed manualy in new browser profile. Selenium uses a temporary browser profile and manual tests in user's browser profile can be sometimes irelevant. hope it helps to move forward.

Comment: Check the visibility of this textbox is controled by the css of itself or by its parent container (parent container invisible, so all element inside it are invisible too)?  if controled by parent container, you should find the visible parent container, then find the textbox inside parent container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again use CSS selector as **#contact-info-view-emergency_contact_name** is the only difference.

```
input[id = "emergency-contact"][data-sync-to-element = "#contact-info-view-emergency_contact_name-243202808"]

input[id = "emergency-contact"][data-sync-to-element = "#contact-info-view-emergency_contact_name-243202809"]
```

Comment: there is no problem to find the element. the issue is about visibility of the element.

Comment: If this selector is used then, he'll be able to send keys as both the fields are independent of each other

Comment: please read the comments, the failure is on clicking on the element, bcs the element is not visible.

Comment: @Prany it is working fine I was using select instead of input thanks buddy

Comment: @SarveshSingh Cheers !

Comment: @Prany Hi  I have a date column in which I am entering the value by SendKeys but then the calendar comes up with that date and I am, not able to move to next element that's why my code is stuck can you please tell how can I remove that calendar and search the next element. Sorry I can not create a new question for 1 day. Please help

Comment: could you add some details ?

Comment: I wrote this code to enter the expiration date by SendKeys
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#passport-exp-date-input-243202807")).sendKeys("2021-05-13");
now  after entering date the calender pops up with this date and due to this I am not able to perform the next action which is selecting gender

@Prany

Comment: the code for thar is below:
Select dropdown111111111111111111111111 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select[id = \"passport-gender-243202807\"][data-sync-to-element = \"#citizenship-info-view-passport_gender-243202807\"]")));
  
dropdown11111111111111111111111.selectByVisibleText("Female");

It is  giving me an error:  “Element is not visible”   Please help @Prany

Comment: It gives me  an error that Female element is not visible because due to calender I am nogt able to click on gender @Prany

Comment: @SarveshSingh You can use Keys.Tab to change the focus but again this is something I have guessed. Please raise a new question with complete details with HTML. Sorry I can't answer in this thread for a different question in the interest of this community.

Comment: Ohk i will create a new question please look that up I tried tab it's not working